# SSH connect using PHP

Tags: php, ssh, exec, phpseclib

I am trying connect to a server via `SSH` using below code:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php'); 
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('mydomain.com'); 
if (!$ssh->login('xxxx', 'xxxx')) { 
   exit('Login Failed'); 
}else{ 
   echo "connected"; 
} 
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
```

It says `connected` but it shows no output for the code 
`echo $ssh->exec('pwd');`

Why?

LOG MESSAGES

```
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:04:65:78:65:63:01:00:00:00  ........exec....
00000010  03:64:69:72                                      .dir

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE (since last: 0.0611, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:00                                      ....
```

Comment: enable logging, and check log, http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#oneoff,logging

Comment: @Nikhil It is a linux operating system

Comment: @AlexAndrei I added the last lines of log.i don't understand what it means.:)

Comment: cool, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/18925697/5043552 and then this http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#interactive. Unfortunately it does not answer the **why** question

Comment: Can you do `ssh xxxx@mydomain.com pwd` from the same machine that you execute the PHP on?

Comment: Do you get the error even if you run read() instead of exec()? Like echo $ssh->read('ls');

Comment: If you do `$ssh->read('ls')` add a `\n` after it. eg. `$ssh->read("ls\n")`. Otherwise it'll be as tho you typed "ls" in the shell but never actually hit enter to have it run it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a 'ssh2_connect' function in php.
After use a 'ssh2_exec' and stock the result in a $var.

at the end you can use a 'stream_get_contents($var);' for return the result code command ssh

Don't forget the 'sleep(1)' function php for prevent bug after launch ssh command.

'ssh2_exec' is a resource php.

- [ssh2_connect](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ssh2-connect.php)
- [ssh2_auth_password](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-password.php)
- [ssh2_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php)
- [sleep php](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sleep.php)
- [stream_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php)